# Cannot view all Button attributes in Android studio.

Tags: android-studio

I actually wanted to the bottom right corner of the screen. But when i run it on the emulator, the button automatically shows up in the top left corner of the screen.
All i want is to view all the attachments available for button im Android studio 3.1

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on Constraint Layout? If so, you need to add a constraint for the left side of the view to the left margin of the screen. By default, the view will fall to the left-top of the activity when it is created. 
You could do this in the Design tab, or go to 'Text' tab and add the following xml code below the other lines of code for the particular widget:

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

If you are using Liner layout, then you need to set the `layout_gravity` property to: `"end | top"`. 
("End" means 'right' and "start" means 'left' - this is a convention for left-to-right languages. )
Hope this helps.